# Plotting an Exponential Best Fit Curve to ggplot2 using Stat_smooth

Tags: r, ggplot2, smoothing, stat

Here is my data:

```
df  <-read.table(text="x   group   y
1   A       0.5
2   A       0.25
3   A       0.1
1   B       0.6
2   B       0.7
3   B       0.2", header=TRUE)
```

What I'm trying to do is plot an exponential Best Fit curve to the data. I would prefer to show the upper trend of an exponential curve to just a normal geom_smooth() curve to convey that values for X=1 tend to be higher and avoid a dip in the Group B curve. My code so far is only generating the points but not the curve. What am I doing wrong?

```
ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) + 
  geom_point() +
  stat_smooth(method = 'nls', formula = y~ a*exp(b *x), aes(colour = 
  'Exponential'), se = FALSE, start = list(a=1,b=1))
```

Comment: You should be using `method.args=list()` for your `start=` parameter. Did `ggplot` not give you an error or warning? What version of `ggplot` are you using?

Comment: For me, there's a warning about the wrong specification of starting values, but then a default is used and I get a line. So this is not reproducible for me.